# Resolving node_modules path to initiating folder across multiple sibling projects with webpack

Tags: node.js, path, webpack

I've several sibling folders / repos:

```
| - A
| |- node_modules
| |- app
|
| - B
| |- node_modules
| |- app
| 
| - C
| |- node_modules
| |- app
```

With cross dependencies, so `A` might require a script in `B`.

```
// A/app/script.js
var bDependency = require('B/app/script.js')


// B/app/script.js
var jquery = require('jquery')
```

In this instance as webpack goes to bundle it, it'll resolve to `jquery` to `B`'s `node_modules` before `A`'s.  This also leads to duplicated modules in the webpack bundle.js as it may resolve to other sibling node_modules folders.  (This is the case even after `new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin()`)

So I would then have to `npm install` a package in `B` even though it's `A` that requires it and already has the library installed.

I'm using resolve, root and modulesDirectories webpack options already for some friendly path resolution.

What I'd like to do is resolve any node_modules paths to the initiating folder first.  Is there a way to achieve this with webpack's path resolving tools, or should I restructure the app to all share one node_modules?

Answer (score 1):

I found the most elegant solution for this was to define a `fallback` property to the `resolve` object pointing to the initiating folder's `node_modules` dir, within the webpack.config.js

```
resolve: {
    // Check the initiating folder's node_modules
    fallback: [
        path.join(__dirname, "node_modules")
    ]
}
```

You can read more about it here: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-fallback

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with Webpack's [NormalModuleReplacementPlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#normalmodulereplacementplugin):

```
new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(new RegExp('path/to/B'), function(result) {
  result.request = result.request.replace("projectB", "projectA");
}),
```

Any imported files matching the regex above will have it's path modified by the function, thus causing modules in `projectB/node_modules` to be grabbed from `projectA/node_modules` instead, preventing duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for the response @maxedison, I've posted the solution I settled on which worked in my instance and scales to any number of sibling repos.